# knitr: How to show two plots of different sizes next to each other?

Tags: r, knitr

I wanted to generate two images of different sizes, but show them side-by-side. Is this possible?

This works, but then they have to be the same size:

````
```{r two_plots_same_size_side_by_side, fig.width=5, fig.height=5}
    plot(...)
    plot(...)
```
````

This doesn't work, but it could since in Markdown, lines that are separated by a single newline, appear on the same line.

````
```{r normal_plot, fig.width=5, fig.height=5}
    plot(...)
```
```{r tall_plot, fig.width=5, fig.height=9}
    plot(...)
```
````

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another option, if you're outputting to HTML is to use the `out.extra=` chunk option, and set them to be float objects within a block. For example.

````
```{r fig.width=4, fig.height=6,echo=FALSE,out.extra='style="float:left"'}
plot(cars)
```{r fig.width=8, fig.height=6,echo=FALSE, out.extra='style="float:left"'}
plot(cars)
```
````

Comment: That's pretty cool. I'll just add <div style="clear: both;"></div> after the second plot in case there's any text. Thanks

Comment: If you have the option to incorporate raw HTML, you may be better off putting them in a `disply:block;` container.

Answer (score 9):

One option would be to make a single wide graph with the R commands and give `knitr` just the one graph to deal with, maybe something like:

````
```{r fig.width=10, fig.height=9}
layout( cbind( c(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0), rep(2,9) ) )
plot(...)
plot(...)
```
````

Answer (score 9):

Yet another option is to use a vector for `out.width` or `out.height`, if you do not mind resizing the plots, e.g.

````
```{r out.width=c('500px', '300px'), fig.show='hold'}
boxplot(1:10)
plot(rnorm(10))
```
````

Comment: @nachocab are you using the latest version of knitr?

Comment: Do you mind posting code for the same thing for Latex? Thanks.

Comment: @dariaa Something like `<<out.width=c('3in', '5in'), fig.show='hold'>>=`

Comment: Thank you @Yihui. Could you please take a look at this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31992128/custom-layout-for-2-plots-using-knitr ?

Answer (score 7):

You can also use grid.arrange from gridExtra which works with grob or ggplot objects

```
require(gridExtra)
pre_fig <- rasterGrob(readPNG("paper_figures/surf_0000.png"), interpolate=TRUE)
post_fig <- rasterGrob(readPNG("paper_figures/surf_0044.png"), interpolate=TRUE)
grid.arrange(pre_fig, post_fig, ncol=2)
```

Comment: maybe first we should do `install.packages(c("png","grid","gridExtra")) `