# Custom layout for 2 plots using knitr

Tags: r, plot, latex, knitr, scatter-plot

What I want is to display 2 figures next to each other in one row, so that the first one is square and the second one takes all the remaining width, it should be wider than the first one (I use `knitr` and LaTeX).

I tried using `r` `layout` and specify `out.width` and `out.height` in a figure chunk options, but I could not get it right and I'm not sure this is the right approach.

And in general, it is better to configure figure size in chunk options, right? But what's the best approach for more complex plot layouts?

Comment: Are you having issues with getting the figures in one row or just the formatting part once they are in one row?

Comment: No, I got them in one row, and I wanted them to be of the same width, I would be okay with the result. I'm struggling with the different widths part, and I could get it right as well, if the first image did not have to be square.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the gridExtra package and specify the '`widths =`' and '`ncol =`' parameters, in order to render several plots on the same line (with same heights), each of these had his own width.

**A)** *e.g*, to render 2 graphics on the same row, with exactly the same heights but the first one is 3 times largest (widhts = 3) than the second one (widths = 1). Assuming 2 ggplots-graphics are previously assigned to graph1 & graph2 objects in your environment :

```
> gridExtra::grid.arrange(name = 'onelinegraph',
>                         gridExtra::arrangeGrob(graph1,graph2,
>                                                ncol=2, 
>                                                widths = c(3,1)
>                                                 )
>                          )
```

**B)** You maybe want to nest several line in this way. In order to made several plots for each line, you have to design your gridExtra-plot 'line by line'. *E.g*, if you want a plot on the entire first line (graph0 is a ggplot-object), then 2 plots which are side-by-side in the second line (graph1 & graph2) :

```
gridExtra::grid.arrange(name = '2linesgraph', 
                        nrow=2,
                        graph0,
                        gridExtra::arrangeGrob(ncol=2,
                                               widths = c(3,1)
                                               graph1, 
                                               graph2, 
                                               )
                          )
```

Here, the first line have the same height than the second line (with graph1 & graph2 side-by-side). The second line is like in the previous *e.g* : one of these 2 plots on the same line is 3 times largest than the other.

**C)** Last but not least, you could nest several arrangeGrob() inside the grid.arrange() call, in order to specify differents dims for each line of your graph.

Best regards,