# RMarkdown: ggplot into a table

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, knitr

There are already a few questions considering ggplots in RMarkdown but none has answered my question as how to put a ggplot into a table with kable() by knitr.
I ve tried this link:

[How can I embed a plot within a RMarkdown table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39362183/how-can-i-embed-a-plot-within-a-rmarkdown-table)

But have not had any luck so far. Any ideas?

The idea was to put all plots into a list with

`a<-list(p1,p2,p3...)`

and then having the table with

`{r}kable(a)`

Additional text should also be able to be included

```
b<-("x","y","z",...)
kable (c(a,b),col.names=c())
```

Thanks for your help

Frieder

Comment: Can you maybe explain why you want the plots in a table maybe it is sufficiënt to use sub plots and sub captions like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546365/subfigures-or-subcaptions-with-knitr?noredirect=1&lq=1)?

Comment: That is unfortunatly the requirement. It needs to be in a format of a table. I want to replace manual creation of Word Docs to save time.

Answer (score 0):

I experimented some with this and the following is the best I could come up with. This is a complete markdown document you should be able to paste into RStudio and hit the Knit button.

Two relevant notes here.

- Setting the file links directly into kable doesn't work as it is wrapped in html such that it is interpreted as text, so we need to `gsub()` it in. An alternative is to set `kable(..., escape = FALSE)`, but it is a risk that other text might cause problems.
- Also, the chunk option `results = 'asis'` is necessary to have the `print(kab)` return raw html.

I don't know if these are problems for the real application.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "me"
date: "02/06/2020"
output: html_document
---

```{r, results = 'asis'}
library(ggplot2)
library(svglite)

n <- length(unique(iris$Species))
data <- split(iris, iris$Species)

# Create list of plots
plots <- lapply(data, function(df) {
  ggplot(df, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
    geom_point()
})

# Create temporary files
tmpfiles <- replicate(n, tempfile(fileext = ".svg"))

# Save plots as files, get HTML links
links <- mapply(function(plot, file) {
  # Suit exact dimensions to your needs
  ggsave(file, plot, device = "svg", width = 4, height = 3)
  paste0('<figure><img src="', file, '" style = "width:100%"></figure>')
}, plot = plots, file = tmpfiles)

# Table formatting
tab <- data.frame(name = names(plots), fig = paste0("dummy", LETTERS[seq_len(n)]))
kab <- knitr::kable(tab, "html")

# Substitute dummy column for figure links
for (i in seq_len(n)) {
  kab <- gsub(paste0("dummy", LETTERS[i]), links[i], kab, fixed = TRUE)
}
print(kab)
```
````

Answer (score 0):

I have found my way around it as described in the link I posted.

I. Saved my plot as a picture
II. Used `sprintf()` to insert picture into table with this command from Rmarkdown: 
`![](path/to/file)`

Poor, but it works. If anybody finds a solution, I will always be interested in smart coding.