# Persistently storing a ggplot2 qplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table

I tried to reproduce [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38660665) on how to use grid.arrange with two plots, with the sole adjustment that I change some of my data in between. The strange thing is that this changes the first plot that I stored. An example:

```
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)

dt <- data.table(x=1:200, y=rnorm(200)) # Sample data

t1 <- qplot(y, data=dt) # Histogram of y
t1 # Show plot

dt[, y := x] # Change y to x
t1 # t1 changed...
```

I'm assuming that this is somehow intended behavior of ggplot2. Hence, my question is whether it is somehow possible to make `t1` persistent to this change, i.e., to store the plot in a way that it doesn't change if the underlying data is changed.

My use case is an `rmarkdown` file in which I want to show the unchanged and changed variable side by side.

[image: Plot before and after y has been changed, respectively]

Comment: There must be something different about your actual code because I get an error when I run the above commands because `y` is not defined outside of `dt`. Somehow you are connecting the two. Please try to make sure your example is [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Because pointers and assign by reference for data.table

Comment: You don't get this behavior with ```tibbles``` from the ```tidyverse```.

Comment: @MrFlick I was missing the `data=dt` in qplot(...).

Comment: @ClaytonStanley, you're right, `data.table` causes this. When creating t1 as `t1 <- qplot(y, data=as.data.frame(dt))`, the problem does not occur. I guess that's the solution then.

Comment: You can also use the copy command if you want a more data.table idiomatic way to show that you want a fresh mem allocation of that table.

Comment: Thanks! That's the right solution for me actually. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it