# How to set different sizes for plots in the same block with knitr?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, figure

I'm trying to create a html with markdown. I want to include several plots using a for loop like this:

````
```{r plotofnas, echo=FALSE, fig.width=2, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
for (i in list) { 
  barplot(i)
  plot(i)
}
````

The problem is that I want different sizes for the first and the second plot in the loop, specifically, I want the barplot to have a smaller width than the other plot. Looking for a solution I came across the fig.width option, but this will change the size of all of my plots, not only the barplots. Is there a possibility to only change the size of specific plots in one block in markdown?

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/a/47339394/7162131 relevant?

Comment: Thank you! The answer referring to http://michaeljw.com/blog/post/subchunkify/ provides a way how to do it. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. The picture does not show. There is just one line like this included for every picture `## <img src="../output/Variablen-2020-11-19_files/figure-html/sub_chunk_7191-1.png" width="384" />`. Probably just a small problem... but I don't know much about knitr.

Comment: Did you set `results='asis'` in the chunk options?

Comment: Perfect! It works now. The only problem remaining is the text I want to put out in between different plots. I have several print statements to put out a bunch of variables and with asif everything is written in one line and hardly readable. Is there a possibiliy to avoid this?

Comment: You could try to remove `results='asis'` and use the function `knitr::asis_output()` only at the desired output. For example, place it only around the code that outputs `<img src="..."/>`.

Answer (score 1):

In the chunk title, this might work:

`{r out.width=c('500px','300px','500px'), fig.show='hold'}`

This example is for 3 plots with the second having a smaller width than the first and third.

You could also do it with proportions if you wanted to shrink the entire image:

`{r out.width=c('40%','20%','40%'), fig.show='hold'}`

This answer was helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14064253/12910533